# Finder: Select a file after Copy & Paste

Tags: macos, finder, copy-paste

When I copy and paste a file in Windows, the last inserted file is selected automatically in the destination folder. Then I can (for example) press F2 to rename it.

When I copy and paste a file in OS X, the last inserted file is NOT selected in the destination folder. When I want to rename it, I have to look for it, select it and press Enter.

Is there a setting (or a shortcut) in OS X to select (or highlight) the last inserted file(s)?

Comment: What version of OS X are you running?

Comment: OS X El Capitan 10.11.5

Comment: So are you saying that the behavior shown in grgarside's answer isn't acting the same for you?

Comment: Please have a look at my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a current selection, the Paste action will select the new pasted file or folder. Therefore, make sure you don't have a current selection when pasting and the file or folder will be selected when you paste.

A quick way to deselect any currently selected items before pasting is ⌥⌘A. If you'd like more automation in this, you can use Keyboard Maestro or equivalent to intercept a ⌘V and press ⌥⌘A first if you wish this to occur every time you paste.

[image: gif of Finder to demonstrate]

[image: gif of two Finder windows to demonstrate]

This answer applies to OS X 10.11.5 and I have also tested it in OS X 10.11.6b1.

Comment: You said, "_If you don't have a current selection, the Paste action will select the new pasted file or folder._" and if I'm understanding this correctly then I find this statement to be false.  In other words, just as expressed by the OP, when I paste an object (file and or folder) in Finder, to e.g. and empty folder, the object(s) pasted do not have focus and they are not highlight in the destination location upon the completion of the paste operation. Am I misunderstanding what you're trying to say?

Comment: @user3439894 Nope, that is what I meant and that is the functionality I see. See my added gif to my answer.

Comment: That is not the behavior I experience and it may have to do with the version of OS X, so you might what to qualify what version of OS X your answer applies to.

Comment: @user3439894 Edited, what version of OS X are you using?

Comment: I'm using OS X 10.8.5, however that is not how I was testing. If I copy an object in Finder and paste it to a different location in Finder, the object does not have focus afterwards.  If I do as in your .gif, yes the object has focus.  However that is not how I normally copy and paste objects in Finder.

Comment: @user3439894 Like my second gif?

Comment: This may well be OS X version related then.  The behavior of your first .gif works in OS X 10.8.5, however the behavior of your second .gif does not.

Comment: I'm using OS X 10.11.5 and I found out the following (no matter if there is a current selection or not): **1.** If I copy and paste a file within the same folder, the inserted file is selected. **2.** If I copy and paste a file between different folders, the inserted file is NOT selected. _My question remains: How to select the last inserted file(s) in a folder?_

Answer (score 0):

I have a walk-around solution of this problem by using the BetterTouchTool. You can assign a sequence of actions to one Shortcut, such as Control-V (in the following snapshot), which can trigger a series of actions involving deselection, paste, sorted by added date, and highlight the upper most item.

[image: BetterTouchTool]

Answer (score -3):

I'll probably be down voted in this answer, but I tried in my El Capitan as the OP described and it never ends selected, it does not work as Windows. As long I still think somethings are still easier in Windows, an O.S. it's about a culture, the usability solution, and may be a better idea dance as the music is playing. The best way to do this task is by OS X way, after paste the file, to click on it and click again (not double click, just click wait click) to edit the filename. The Mac OS X is an interface that has a lot of the old classic O.S. that was made for mouse, not keyboard, unlike the Windows that has a lot of DOS still in the "blood".

Personally, I work with two windows opened and drag-and-drop (alt to copy) as even Bill dreamed when he copied Apple's O.S..

Comment: Are you absolutely and beyond any doubt sure, ideally based on publicly available information, that there is no way to accomplish what the OP asked for?

Comment: I don't know way you ask me like this. I answered as (obviously) my opinion, I'm not the owner of the truth so I start the second paragraph by "Personally". It's hard to discuss some points of OS, people get offended when the answer is not they want to hear. I did work with a lot of different OS in my life, since were invented, and to try to twist an OS work as another is usually a bad idea - IMO.